# make "cannot find libraries"

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to compile til parameter estimation tool PEST (http://www.pesthomepage.org/) for linux.

According to the PEST-manual I did:

```
make -f pest.mak all
```

but I get following error message:

```
gfortran -c -O3 -static pestdata.for 
gfortran -c -O3 -static pest.for   
gfortran -c -O3 -static pestsub2.for
gfortran -c -O3 -static writall.for
gfortran -c -O3 -static pardef.for
gfortran -c -O3 -static readpest.for
gfortran -c -O3 -static runpest.for
gfortran -static -o pest \
                pest.o pestsub1.o pestsub2.o dercalc.o modrun.o writall.o \
        linpos.o lapack1.o writsig.o common.o \
        pgetcl.o pestwait.o writint.o pardef.o\
                drealrd.o space.o optwt.o cgsolve.o compress.o \
                readpest.o runpest.o lsqr.o orthog.o ms_stubs.o pestdata.o
/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pest] Error 1
```

After goggling I have tried different things, but without results. Can somebody please help
me?

Regards Tanja

Comment: what does the exact command line executed by make look like?

Comment: Incase you are new to `make`, it's effectively a rule base scripting language.  What's failing here isn't make itself but one of the commands it's used.  Make will show what commands as it uses them, so we really need some output from before these errors to know what's going wrong.

Comment: That said, this does look like `ld` is failing to find some libraries: `libgfortran.so` `libm.so`... so the problem is most likely that you didn't install the required dependencies before compiling.

Comment: @Philip Couling I've been thinking that too, but libm.so is so commonly used that it's hard to believe it is missing. This is why I asked for the exact command line that fails.

Comment: @Ronald Yes, there's certainly a lot of information missing from the question.  I prefer to information while requesting more information from the OP.  Even if it's only explaining the meaning of an error in plain English, it's frequently enough to let them answer their own question.

Comment: thank you. Now again my question: what happens if you, as a test, remove the `-static` flag in the last command line and execute `make` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions to a problem shouldn't be hidden in comments, which is why I write this answer.

The `make` output shows that the Makefile tries to link statically.
That requires the libraries that can be linked statically, notably libm.a, libgfortran.a, libquadmath.a and libc.a

A possible solution is to remove the `-static` flag in the final step.
The resulting executable will of course need the shared objects (libm.so and friends) in order to be able to run. In most situations that's not a problem though.